# Where is the default Mac screen saver location?

Tags: macos, screensaver

Where is the directory to the default screen savers on Max OS X Lion?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are asking?

Comment: I wanted to look at the .qtz file in Quartz Composer to see how the Word of the Day screen saver was made. And to see what font it used. FYI, it uses Baskerville SimiBold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defaults screensavers are in `/System/Library/Screen Savers`.